# Can't access JS Object values by keys without storing in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, express

So, I ran into a weird bug in javascript.

```
const obj1 = await chartService.callAPIConversion({ unix_timestamp: Math.floor(activity[0].createdAt.getTime() / 1000) })

console.log(obj1.usd_rate);
//THIS WORKS -> returns proper value

console.log(await (chartService.callAPIConversion({ unix_timestamp: Math.floor(activity[0].createdAt.getTime() / 1000) })).usd_rate);
//THIS DOESNOT WORK -> returns undefined
```

Why am I not able to get the key without using a variable?

Comment: `(await`…`).usd_rate`, not `await (`…`).usd_rate`. `.` has higher precedence than `await`.

Comment: Related: [Understanding await with Javascript array indexing](/q/66050816/4642212), [What is the Operator Precedence of Await?](/q/48218744/4642212), and some of their linked posts, though these could use some improvement…

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to access it without creating a variable because your are retrieving values from a JavaScript object not an API call. Once the JS object called `obj1` gets the informations related to your API call you can now access these informations threw the call of your JS object.

Comment: The actual issue was actually due to operator precedence as mentioned in the first comment of the post. Thanks anyways.